# How to make a set of a space capsule?

Tags: filming

I am going to make a short film for the 2019 Cinespace contest created by NASA. 
The short is going to take place inside a space capsule. It has to look something like this:

[image: Soyuz capsule]

How do you guys suggest I do it? Do I build a set from scratch? If so... how do I construct it? 
Thanks!

Comment: Kinda depends on your budget. You could do anything from MDF, bottle caps and hot glue, to commissioning JPL to build you a full-size replica.

Answer (score 2):

This really depends on your budget.

Low Budget:
Find a room which allready looks futuristic with a lot of tech or stuff that looks like buttons and displays. Like in your image, you could make a little bole eye windows with some salad dish, put a screen behind which plays space stuff.

High budget:
Build a little wood cage, also add a little window which shows space and adds natural light.
Then go to home depo and just buy a lot of diffrent knobs and buttons.

Answer (score 1):

to addition to ITnoob, you might like to add some green screen and cgi to enhance the look. But this depence on your skills.
If you have a bit of electronical knowledge, also include some blinking leds and lights